# Pyperclip coping in loop

Tags: python, clipboard, pyperclip

I need to copy data in clipboard through loop.

I did this, i added sleep for 0.25s, and it works i guess. But sometimes it loses data. So my question is how to copy to clipboars through loop rightly. Is there any way to do it without delay?

```
import time
from pyperclip import copy

for i in range(50):
    copy(str(i))
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

Comment: What's the point?

Comment: what is that you want to achive? i.e. what you do in these 0.25s while data stay in the clipboard?

Comment: @Daviid, I'm writing an application that pastes text into the clipboard and picks it up
from there via local network between computers, so i need it to copy list of data(strings) into clipboard. But if i do it in loop without delay, it just copies last data in clipboard.

Comment: @buran, I'm writing an application that pastes text into the clipboard and picks it up from there via local network between computers, so i need it to copy list of data(strings) into clipboard. But if i do it in loop without delay, it just copies last data in clipboard

Comment: Using clipboard for this is really unreliable. There are plenty of better ways to achieve this.by network communication between computers (e.g. using sockets) or via db in the middle (e.g. redis or other). This, of course is based solely on broad description you just provide